# Safari and too many redirection

Tags: wordpress, redirect, safari

I have a website which is perfectly fine when I'm on firefox, or Chrome, or IE. But I have a Too many redirect error when I'm going with it with Safari.

It is strange because, when I go on the home page : http://www.promenade-sainte-catherine.com it's ok, and if I go on an other page, I get the error. If I refresh the page, I can see it.

I really don't see where this comes from.

For information :
This bug is only on Safari Mac, on iPhone it works well (using wp touch).
Here is the list of plugin I use :

Advanced Custom Fields
Contact Form 7
Google sitemap plugin
Slideshow Gallery
TinyMCE Advanced
User Role Editor
WordPress SEO (I have deactivated this one, but still the same result)
WP Columns
WP Sliding Login/Dashboard Panel
WPtouch

Thanks for your help

EDIT : 
HTACCESS :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a problem with your `permalink` settings - in your admin go to `Settings > Permalinks`, click save, and give it another try.

Comment: not sure what that means, can you update your question with the contents of your `.htaccess`?

Comment: That is just the standard wordpress rewrite, which is required for fancy permalinks. What do you have set as you permalink structure?

Comment: In your Admin, what do you have for your permalink structure in `Settings->Permalinks`?

Comment: Actually, your permalinks work fine, you just don't have a post called `sample-post` - http://www.promenade-sainte-catherine.com/chantier/

Comment: yep, sorry, i've just copied the row. The weirdest thing is on safari, when I click on http://www.promenade-sainte-catherine.com/chantier I get redirected on http://www.promenade-sainte-catherine.com/actualites

Comment: It seems like you have a plugin installed that is messing with your redirects.

Comment: Well in fact, I don't know, sometimes it does, sometimes not. I really don't know what I did to have this problem :s

Comment: And now it works. Does it mean there is something wrong with permalinks ?

Comment: That should fix it, but if not I would look at other plugins that might be affecting your redirects.